# Jquery Show and Hide on hover

Tags: jquery

I was want to show a div when hover on an image i found a demo i follow but it a toggle hover i want to show the div only when mouse hover on it once and hide again when mouse away i didn't know what i need to change in the code to work like i want i am new in jquery here the code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

        $('.show_hide').hover(function () {
            $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$('.show_hide').hover(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

to:

```
$('.show_hide').hover(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").slideDown();
}, function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The $.hover function accepts second callback, that is called on mouse leave, so you just have to toggle the element once again:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').hover(function () {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideDown();
    }, function () {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideUp();
    }
    );

});
```

Comment: Using `slideToggle` twice is unreliable and can cause some undesired results

Comment: nice tip, 10x. Changed to sludeDown/sludeUp

Comment: What do you mean nice tip, more like nice answer from me. see my unedited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#slidingDiv").hide();
            $("#show_hide").show();
            $('#show_hide').hover(function () {
                $("#slidingDiv").slideDown();
            }, function () {
                $("#slidingDiv").slideUp();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="show_hide">Show / Hide</a>
    <div id="slidingDiv">
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mouseEnter and mouseLeave to do this

```
$('#ImgToHover').mouseEnter(function(){
 // Action to perform to add hover
});

$('#ImgToHover').mouseLeave(function(){
 // Action to perform to remove hover
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#div").mouseout(function(){
        $("#div").hide();
    }).mouseover(function(){
        $("#div").show();
    });
});
```

Documented here: http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0  /jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(


function()

{

$("#b1").click(function(){

$("p").hide();



})

$("#b2").click(function(){

$("p").show();

})

$("#fade").click(function()

{

$("p").fadeOut(2000);

})

$("#fade1").click(function()

{

$("p").fadeIn(5000);

})

});


</script>

</head>


<body>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.


If you click on me, I will disappear.

If you click on me, I will disappear.

If you click on me, I will disappear.

If you click on me, I will disappear.

If you click on me, I will disappear.

If you click on me, I will disappear.

If you click on me, I will disappear.

</p>

<input type="button" value="Hide" id="b1"/>

<input type="button" value="Show" id="b2"/>

<input type="button" value="Fade" id="fade"/>

<input type="button" value="Fade" id="fade1"/>

</body>



</html>


Replace Click() with hover().
```